# Fujitsu Primergy RX100 S6 Windows Web Server 2k8 R2 Hard Drives not found

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-server-2008-r2, raid, rack

I got a question about our Fujitsu Primergy RX100 S6. We want to install Windows Web Server 2008 R2 on a complete brand new RAID 1. The BIOS finds both of the hard drives and also the virtual disk shows up at the boot.

The problem is that the installer of Windows Web Server 2008 R2 does not find these hard drives in the hard drive explorer of the install wizard and we cannot install the system. We already tried to add sata drivers from usb while you can choose them in the hard drive menu.

Some of these driver packages were like empty folders in the explorer from the install wizard of Win Web Server 2k8 but they were definitely copied them to the usb drive. Other ones comes up but they doesnt fixed it.

I have also read about the ServerView DVD which we dont have from the Retail. I downloaded these DVD from the Fujitsu Support website and booted from it with an USB Stick, the wizard comes up and after a few clicks it wants to download external features and returns with an 404 error.

I would appreaciate it if someone know which drivers or which DVD will fix the issue.

Much thanks!

Comment: Sounds like windows needs drivers for the RAID card to be active when you're installing it.  The only thing I found were here:  https://www.fujitsu.com/global/support/products/computing/servers/primergy/drivers/legal-windows.html

Comment: @Matt thanks for your help so far! But the document you postet about doesn't contain anything towards the Fujitsu Primergy RX100 S6 Product.

Comment: that's where google brought me, and then to a download.  If that's not the right one, try searching the fujitsu site.  It used to be that when installing windows you could input additional drivers for things like RAID cards.

Comment: We already tried to add drivers in the setup but the hard drives didnt show up.